# deploy Django 1.10 project with Python 3.5 to Azure

Tags: azure, python, django

just wanna know if I can deploy Django 1.10 project with Python 3.5 to Azure Cloud? I mean, I do not develop it using Visual Studio but only text editor (Atom or Sublime),,thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can run a basic Linux VM and then install your project using a simple script.

Salvo.

Comment: thank you,,I only familiar with aws ec2 ,and aws is so easy to open up a ubuntu server and deploy django project , however, this time I have to only use Azure, let me try it